# ¿Por qué no se imprime en pantalla mi argumento en el comando "print" de este programa?

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy aprendiendo PyGame, más concretamente como utilizar los relojes.

Tengo este programa en el que quiero mostrar en pantalla el reloj actual en milisegundos pero no me aparece nada.

Pongo el programa:

```
import pygame, sys

# Setting up pyGame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock ()

currentTime = 0
startPointTime = 0

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            startPointTime = pygame.time.get_ticks ()

currentTime = pygame.time.get_ticks ()
print (f"current time: {currentTime} Start Point Time: {startPointTime}")

pygame.display.flip ()
clock.tick (60)
```

Despúes de almacenar en la variable "currentTime", quiero ver en la consola de forma visual el valor que se almacena en cada frame con el "print" posterior, pero cuando corro el programa no se muestra, pero tampoco me da ningún tipo de error.

Comment: El `print` está fuera del bucle `while`. Mientras no se salga del bucle no se imprimirá nada.

Comment: Los comentarios no llevan votos. Solo llevan confirmaciones de otras personas. Los comentarios son efimeros y se terminan borrando.

Answer (score 1):

al hacer un print no te lo mostrara en la pantalla, si no en la consola, si quieres imprimir texto en una ventana de pygame debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
pygame.font.init()
fuente = pygame.font.Font(None, 100)#para cambiar el tamaño solo cambia el numero
texto = fuente.render(f"current time: {currentTime} Start Point Time: {startPointTime}")
screen.blit(texto, [x,y])
```

espero te ayude